# How to get Dsname current generation

Tags: mainframe, jcl, tso

I have these datasets.

```
FILE.AB1.NAME.G1000V00

FILE.AB2.NAME.G1000V00

FILE.AB3.NAME.G1000V00
```

When I enter FILE.AB1.NAME(0) I get FILE.AB1.NAME.G1000V00.

But when I enter FILE.*.NAME(0), I get "No data set names found"

How can I get all the following listed using (0)?

```
FILE.AB1.NAME.G1000V00

FILE.AB2.NAME.G1000V00

FILE.AB3.NAME.G1000V00
```

Comment: You write "enter FILE.*.NAME(0)" -- where do you enter this?

Comment: Data Set List Utility on the Dsname Level line.

Comment: DSLIST does not support use of relative generation numbers in parentheses.

Comment: Thanks. How would I be able to get all generation (0) datasets for FILE.*.NAME?

Comment: Do a listc and process the results through a program of your choice.

Comment: Thanks. I've never done a listc. Is that in 3.4 (utilities/dslist)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
(0)
```

at the end of the dataset name you will get the latest generation of a Generation Data Group (GDG).
If you use

```
(-1)
```

you will get the penultimate generation of the GDG and so on.

If you want to list all datasets with the same generation you could use

```
FILE.**.G1000V00
```

Comment: Which is all very well if all the GDGs have a generation number in common.